# How do I describe the phrase “It do can I”?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions

If I change **“I can do it”** to **“it do can I”** How do I describe this way of writing?

I think “I wrote it backwards” or “I wrote it back to front” can be misleading as a mirror writing because it can mean each alphabet letter is written backwards.

Is “I wrote backwards by a word” idiomatic? Or what other way should I describe it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I wrote the sentence backwards" could describe either situation: it could mean that you reversed the order of the words, or that you reversed the order of all the letters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be called "*writing with the reverse **word** order*" (in contrast to the **letter** one).